# Update only a single property of a given object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity called worker and each worker has a property called active which is boolean.

My twig is an index that shows the list of workers with active=true.
I have a button in front of each worker, when I press this button I want it to change that worker's active property to false.

**The problem**: I couldn't figure out how to change that value in the controller without making a form since I'm still an amateur when it comes to Symfony

Here's my twig:

```
<table id="file_export" class="table table-striped table-bordered">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Active</th>
                <th>edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for worker in workers %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ worker.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ worker.Firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ woker.Lastname }}</td>
                <td>{{ worker.active ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ path('worker_edit', {'id': worker.id}) }}" class="btn btn-round btn-info" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and my controller (which doesn't work):

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="worker_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Worker $worker): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('edit'.$worker->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $worker->setActive(false);

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($worker);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
    }
```

Comment: When your page is rendered and sent to the browser it is just static HTML. You could use javascript to perform some action when a button is clicked. With an AJAX request you could ask the server to toggle the status of "active". To seperate things you could start with a new route and a new controller action that toggles the state of the given entity..

Comment: do you need this CSRF token at all? I‘d use the id to get a Worker from doctrine, set it to not active and flush. Why do you need a csrf token? are your users authenticated?

Comment: well The admin is connected and he's the one who can deactivate workers

Comment: oh wait, haha it worked when I removed the csrf token from the controller. Thank you very much man.

Answer (score 1):

you actually have to add a csrf token to your path call:

```
path('worker_edit', {'id': worker.id, '_token': csrf_token('worker'~worker.id)})
```

or otherwise your check for the csrf token obviously cannot succeed.

however, since a link will trigger a GET request, you have to look into

```
$request->query->get('_token')
```

in the `isCsrfTokenValid` call.

As a hint: give your routes and actions semantically better names. Like ... "worker_deactivate", if it is used to deactivate a worker (which it apparently is). <strike>it's also quite common, to call the routed methods of a controller *action*Action, so that would be `deactivateAction`.</strike>

Comment: I agree with your answer, though it's worth noting that symfony no longer recommends using `Action` as part of controller names. See the latest [best practices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#controller-action-naming).

Comment: Sorry but I added the csrf token to my path and it still doesn't work

Comment: @BetaRay I have no way of checking your work. Can only tell you, that this would be the way to do it. but "it still doesn't work" isn't particularly helpful in determining anything.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make HTTP requests without reloading the web page, then you've to go for AJAX calls. A very simple implementation using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) that doesn't require any additional packages (like jQuery) would look like this:

```
<script>
(function() {
    document.getElementById({{worker.id}}).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch({{path('worker_edit', {'id': worker.id})}}, {method: 'POST'})
            .then(function(response) {
                // you can catch eventual errors here, and of course refresh your button or display a nice message..

            });
    });
})()
</script>
<table id="file_export" class="table table-striped table-bordered">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Active</th>
                <th>edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for worker in workers %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ worker.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ worker.Firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ woker.Lastname }}</td>
                <td>{{ worker.active ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ path('worker_edit', {'id': worker.id}) }}" class="btn btn-round btn-info" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

p.s: The javascript code above is not tested as I have to reproduce the twig and controller, but it could give you an idea on how to achieve the task.

Comment: I think I haven't formulated my question properly. My goal is not making a request without reloading the page. instead I want it so that when I press the button, the value inside the database changes to false and I get redirected to my page.